# Maintain campaign tracking in the URL?

Tags: google-analytics

The site is a typical web store with products, payments and a checkout. I've attached campaign tracking codes, utm_campaign, utm_source etc. to links that users are clicking. And when they arrive on the site the url looks like

```
 example.com?utm_source=email&utm_campaign=...
```

Do I need to persist these in the url throughout the site? Will Analytics be able to measure conversions  from different campaigns once they move on to a difference page?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to persist them through the page.

Google Analytics assigns an id to the visitor which is maintained in a cookie and is used to stitch a sequence of pageviews together into a session.

If a session starts with an url that has campaign parameter GA will attribute the whole session to that campaign. It will also attribute following visits to the same campaign unless those following visits can be attributed to another marketing campaign (e.g. because they have campaign parameters of their own).